# Are there any other stories set in Charles Stross Palimpsest universe?

Tags: charles-stross

I enjoyed Palimpsest by Charles Stross. It seems to be a one-off novella, I was wondering if any of his other short stories, etc. are set in that universe? Wikipedia was of no help...

Comment: At one time there were several excellent stories set in that universe. Unfortunately, the timeline in which they occurred was wiped out, so they're now as lost as the Cathedral of Chalesm. I have discovered a truly marvelous early draft of one of them, which this comment form is too small to contain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are currently no other stories in that universe, the author himself has suggested a possibility that Palimpsest may [eventually become a novel itself](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2011/05/palimpseste.html#comment-142029).

Answer (score 5):

No, there aren't. It was written as a one-off to round out a short story collection.

Answer (score 0):

Palimpsest is one of Stross' most self-contained stories. Although Stross makes statements that *seem* to deny this, I find that the themes that permeate *Accelerando* tend to show up in most of the rest of his work, in some form or another. The use of time travel in Palimpsest contrasts with the Eschaton books in which The Eschaton explicitly forbids redacting the past.